# Finding DPI in silverlight application

Tags: silverlight

I am working on silverlight application and finding the DPI of Canvas.

so how I can find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All measurements in Silverlight are in logical pixels where there are 96 DPI, regardless of the actual DPI of the device being rendered on.